# acmart: ugly email addresses -- how to avoid line breaking?

Tags: line-breaking, acmart, email

`acmart` is creating very ugly line breaks in some of my colleagues' email addresses, and I don't know how to fix this since things like `\small` (to reduce font size) and `\hbox` (to avoid line breaking) don't work here. Is there a way I can convince LaTeX to avoid breaking the email addresses?

Here's an example of the code:

```
\documentclass[sigconf]{acmart}

\begin{document}

\title{Paper Title}

\author{Author 1}
\email{email@domain.com}
\affiliation{Affiliation}

\author{Author 2}
\email{email@domain.com}
\affiliation{Affiliation}

\author{Author 3}
\email{email@domain.com}
\affiliation{Affiliation}

\author{Author With Long Email 1}
\email{long\_long\_long\_address@domain.com}
\affiliation{Affiliation}

\author{Author With Long Email 2}
\email{long\_long\_long\_address@domain.com}
\affiliation{Affiliation}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

And here's the result:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make all emails smaller by redefining \UrlFont. You can avoid the break by redefining \UrlBreakPenalty:

```
\documentclass[sigconf]{acmart}

\begin{document}

\title{Paper Title}

\author{Author 1}
\email{email@domain.com}
\affiliation{Affiliation}

\author{Author 2}
\email{email@domain.com}
\affiliation{Affiliation}

\author{Author 3}
\email{email@domain.com}
\affiliation{Affiliation}

\author{Author With Long Email 1}
\email{long\_long\_long\_address@domain.com}
\affiliation{Affiliation}

\author{Author With Long Email 2}
\email{long\_long\_long\_address@domain.com}
\affiliation{Affiliation}

\begingroup
 %\def\UrlFont{\ttfamily\scriptsize} %smaller email
\mathchardef\UrlBreakPenalty=10000
\maketitle

\endgroup
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome, exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!

Comment: Are there any other ways to do this? It didn't work for my use case (possibly because the email domain contains a hyphen).

Comment: @ElliottSlaughter if you have a new question ask a new question (with a full example). Don't ping individual people.