# acmart: Avoid break in email address with hyphen

Tags: acmart

Using the acmart package, I have an author with an email address whose domain contains a hyphen. This gets broken into two lines by the default acmart styling, and since it's an email (and therefore interprets all commands literally), I'm not able to figure out a way to fix it without modifying acmart itself, which is forbidden in my conference proceedings.

This is similar to [acmart: ugly email addresses -- how to avoid line breaking?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/391157/11376) except the domain contains a hyphen, and therefore the solution presented to that question does not work.

Reproducer:

```
\documentclass[sigconf]{acmart}

\begin{document}

\title{Paper Title}

\author{Author 1}
\email{email@domain.com}
\affiliation{Affiliation}

\author{Author 2}
\email{email@domain.com}
\affiliation{Affiliation}

\author{Author With Long Email 3}
\email{username@longlong.long-domain.ext}
\affiliation{Affiliation}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found an answer. If you add the option `urlbreakonhyphens=false`, then acmart will fix this for you.

```
\documentclass[sigconf,urlbreakonhyphens=false]{acmart}
```

(The rest of the original reproducer is unmodified.)